# Dojo ComboBox DropDown IE scrolling

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox, dojo

I am using dijit ComboBox 1.9.1 on my web page. After keypress I am waiting 0.6s and then send the value to server and get the list of the answers which I fill to ComboBox datastore and open the DropDown with fetched values.
I realize strange thing in IE9: if first DropDown is short it is ok - without scrollbars, than if it longer the scrollbars are visible. After than, if next DropDown is e.g. only one item, scrollbars are visible again which makes the result item completely unreadable. FF is ok with this.

Does somebody know how to solve this or any possible workaround? Resetting the CombBox widget doesn't help.

Comment: Would you be able to post a sample through jsFiddle that we can use to examine a sample of the puzzle?

Comment: @Kolban I tried to get it together, but then realize that jsfiddle.net does not work in IE8. This [sample app](http://jsfiddle.net/VB87u/6/) shows the right scroll bar after long list with short list as well (IE9, not FF). I would like to post screen shots, but I can't. In my app there is a horizontal scrollbar as well, not here.